# Colours overlapping in bar graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, data-science, visualization

I'm trying to use different colours for representing different categories of species in the bar graph  in iris dataset but all the colours are getting overlapped on every bar of the graph
[The bar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USLw9.jpg)

I used this code

```
fig,axes=plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(8,8))
c=['red','green','orange']
axes[0,0].set_title('Sepal Length')
axes[0,0].bar(df['Species'],df['SepalLengthCm'],color=c)
axes[0,1].set_title('Sepal Width')
axes[0,1].bar(df['Species'],df['SepalWidthCm'],color=c)
axes[1,0].set_title('Petal Length')
axes[1,0].bar(df['Species'],df['PetalLengthCm'],color=c)
axes[1,1].set_title('Petal Width')
axes[1,1].bar(df['Species'],df['PetalWidthCm'],color=c)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You are drawing a bar for each individual row of the dataframe. For each bar, the x-position comes from the Species, and the height from the individual Sepal Length. You can use seaborn to create a barplot of the average heigth together with an errorbar:  `sns.barplot(data=df, x='Species', y='Sepal Length', ax=axes[0,0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following tries to explain what's going on in your original code.
To avoid overcrowding, it uses 30 random rows of the iris dataset.

`df['species']` is the species column, containing values `['versicolor', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'virginica', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'setosa', 'virginica', 'setosa', 'virginica', ...]`.

`df['sepal_length']` contains `[6.4, 5.5, 4.7, 6.7, 5.8, 5.6, 4.8, 7.1, 5.8, 6.7, ...]`.

Then `ax.bar(df['species'], df['sepal_length'], color=c)` will create 30 (in this example) bars. One for the first of `df['species']`, `versicolor` with height `6.4`. Then one for `setosa` with height `5.5`. Then again `setosa` height `4.7`.  As the same x-value is used, this bar will be drawn on top of the other one.  The colors won't correspond to the species, they are just the 3 colors repeated for each subsequent row.

It's easier to see using the index to position the bars, and then to imagine all these bars superimposed depending on the species.

```py
import seaborn as sns # easy way to get the iris dataset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(20230210)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, squeeze=False, figsize=(15, 4), gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [10, 1]})
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
df = iris.iloc[np.random.choice(len(iris), replace=False, size=30)].reset_index()
c = ['red', 'green', 'orange']
axs[0, 0].bar(df.index, df['sepal_length'], color=c)
axs[0, 0].margins(x=0.02)
axs[0, 0].set_xticks(df.index, df['species'], rotation=30)
axs[0, 0].set_title('The separate bars drawn')
axs[0, 1].bar(df['species'], df['sepal_length'], color=c)
axs[0, 1].tick_params(axis='x', rotation=30)
axs[0, 1].set_title('Bars superimposed\nper species')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: why bars are superimposed in bar plot]

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @JohanC the comments, I'd recommend using a Seaborn [`barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html?highlight=barplot#seaborn.barplot) for this, but if you just want to use Matplotlib you could do the following (note, this assumes that you want the mean value plotted in each case):

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(8, 8))
c = ['red', 'green', 'orange']

cols = ['SepalLengthCm', 'SepalWidthCm', 'PetalLengthCm', 'PetalWidthCm']

for ax, col in zip(axes.flatten(), cols):
    ax.bar(
        df["Species"].unique(),
        df.groupby("Species")[col].mean(),  # get the mean values
        color=c
    )
    ax.set_title(col)
```

The Seaborn `barplot` by default would calculate the mean and add an error bar based on the standard deviation of the data. This could be done in Matplotlib with:

```
for ax, col in zip(axes.flatten(), cols):
    ax.bar(
        df["Species"].unique(),
        df.groupby("Species")[col].mean(),  # get the mean values
        yerr=df.groupby("Species")[col].std(), # add error
        color=c,
    )
    ax.set_title(col)
```

Comment: Your solution supposes `df["Species"].unique()` and `df.groupby("Species")` have the species in the same order, what's not always the case.  It's safer to use `df1 = df.groupby("species")['sepal_length'].mean()` and then use `df1.index` as x values for the bar.